# RODBC - multiple statements in one sqlQuery() call

Tags: sql, r

In R, I'm getting an error whenever I pass a query with multiple statements to sqlQuery.
For example,

```
sqlQuery(ch, 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;')
```

produces the error

```
[1] "42000 1064 [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.27]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2' at line 1"
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;'"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is an issue related to your use of SQL syntax, rather than `R`. Add the `sql` tag to direct attention to this question appropriately.

Comment: I've tried executing the statement in MySQL Workbench and it runs fine.

Comment: Perhaps you need to escape the semicolon character (I can't remember if it's a special character in R). Try `'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1\; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2\;'`

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Answer (score 0):

First, try one statement `Drop table if exists t1` from R; for me (I am testing with an Access database) this fails, indicating that ODBC does not support `if exists` in my environment. Testing in the MySQL Workbench is not a fair comparison; however, your construct might work with functions provided by the RMySQL package.

ODBC is different in many aspects, so to test if things would work, I normally use Access to connect to the database via ODBC and use the SQL designer. The following does not work there:

```
CREATE TABLE b (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
DROP TABLE b;
```

As separate statements, it works ok.

Comment: I tried just one statement drop-if statement on its own, and it worked.  So ODBC does seem to support this construct in my environment.  I'm wondering if it's the RODBC package that doesn't support multiple sql statements, although other questions on StackOverflow indicate otherwise.